# проблема с сетевым интерфейсом в Linux Mint

Tags: linux, сеть, linux-mint, ifconfig

Уже не помню в последствии чего появилась эта проблема.
Почему-то, виртуальный сетевой интерфейс у меня называется не **lo**, а **wlan0**

```
wlan0: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Локальная петля (Loopback))
        RX packets 227  bytes 18692 (18.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 227  bytes 18692 (18.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

как мне его переименовать?

Comment: для начала можешь посмотреть, что про переименование говорится в `dmesg`... ну и `grep`'нуть `/etc` на предмет `wlan0`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer
 `qwerty@qwerty-pc:~$ dmesg | grep rename `
`[ 2.070608] wlan0: renamed from lo ` 
Выдает это. Видимо, раньше я что-то сделал не так. Я не особо опытный в линукс и не знаю как это исправить

Answer (score 1):

Помогло `sudo aptitude full-upgrade`.
Вопрос закрыт.